# as3 Vector.map and Vector.filter

Tags: actionscript-3, vector

Gone thru the livedocs but the examples are quite sparse.
Can anyone give me some good 'real world' examples of when and why you might use the 
map and filter methods of the new Vector class in Actionscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vector `filter` and `map` methods work just the same as the methods in the Array class of the same name.  Check the following two pages for filter examples for arrays (they work just the same for the Vector class):

http://troyworks.com/blog/2007/12/16/as3-arrayfilter-r0xr/
http://www.onebyonedesign.com/tutorials/array_methods/

I couldn't find any decent as3 map examples, but the jQuery equivalent explains how/why you would use it fairly well:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

As for real world uses, filter is unbelievably useful.  Suppose you have a Vector filled with Employee objects.  You can use the `filter` method as a non-destructive way to get all the Employees whose name starts with "A", or whose salary is greater than $50,000.  The `map` function is similar, but it creates a new Vector and allows you to alter the objects, so you could potentially cast each Employee as a new type, such as HighlyPaidEmployee.